# Event handler registered once for multiple controls - is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

1. JQM page 'operator-modify'.
2. Form 'user-form' inside page.
3. Some controls (text inputs etc) inside form.

Is it possible to register event handler ONCE for these controls?
It would be great to track any changes inside form controls.
If possible - how to do it?

Code fragment below:

```
<div data-role="page" id="operator-modify" data-theme="b">

    <div data-role="content">

        <form id="user-form">
            <label for="user-id-name">ID:</label>
            <input type="text" name="user-id-name" id="user-id-m" data-clear-btn="true"/>
            <label for="user-title-name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="user-title-name" id="user-title-m" data-clear-btn="true"/>
            <label for="user-role-name">Role:</label>
            <input type="text" name="user-role-name" id="user-role-m" data-clear-btn="true"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is not difficult to register 3 identical event handlers, but it seems unflexible solution.

Comment: Post your "multiple control" code, and we'll see what we can do about it.

Comment: Posted in original message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. try this http://jsfiddle.net/UC952/

```
$('input[type="text"]', 'div[data-role="content"]').keydown(function () {
    console.log($('label[for="' + $(this).attr("name") + '"]', 'div[data-role="content"]').text() + ' changed.');
});
```

and a more generic:- `event.target` will provide you the element which triggered the event inside the form.

```
$('#user-form').keydown(function (event) {
   var elem = $(event.target);
    console.log($('label[for="' + elem.attr("name") + '"]', 'div[data-role="content"]').text() + ' changed.');
});
```

Comment: Nopes this will be user-form here, not the element.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I went back and re-read and realized what it was. Also, there's no real reason to use the context selector ( `$('#user-form', 'div[data-role="content"]')` ) when you're targeting an `id`...`$('#user-form')` is sufficient. And your first example binds a handler to each element found, instead of **one**. So does your second handler, but since it's targeting an `id`, it ends up only binding **one**

Comment: Right.. :) i dint notice it, i just copy pasted my above approach and added form :)

Comment: 2PSCoder - you forgot to include event into function parameters

Answer (score 2):

You could use event delegation with something like this:

```
$("#user-form").on("click", 'input[type="text"]', function (e) {
    // `this` refers to the element that was clicked
    // `e.delegateTarget` refers to the element this event is actually bound to (the form)
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Nz6e8/

Which binds one `click` event (to the `form[id="user-form"]` element), but only executes for `input[type="text"]` elements inside of it.

Depending on what you want to bind the event to and what you want to target, you can change the selectors, but should accomplish what you want.

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events